# Serialize collection as JsonObject instead of JsonArray with GSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, serialization, gson

My goal is to serialize a class implementing the Collection interface as JSON object instead of a JSON array. The following class is a simplyfied example:

```
public class CollectionImplementation implements Collection<String> {
  private final List<String> _wrappedList = new LinkedList<>();
  private String _otherField = "asdf";

  @Override
  public boolean add(String e) {
    return _wrappedList.add(e);
  }

  @Override
  ...
}
```

The result of `new Gson().toJson(collectionImplementationInstance)` is:

```
["str1","str2",...]
```

which misses the other field. Instead, I would like to get:

```
{"_wrappedList":["str1","str2"],"_otherField":"asdf"}
```

Is there a way without manually adding all fields to the JSON?

Comment: I figured out that CollectionTypeAdapterFactory is responsible for creating the type adapter which creates a JSON array and ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory would create the type adapter which leads to my goal. I know about delegating to other type adapters but how can I get a valid instance of the type adapter from ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, one can use Reflection to get an instance of the `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` in an own `TypeAdapterFactory`:

```
public class CollectionImplementationTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
  @Override
  public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
    if (!type.getRawType().equals(CollectionImplementation.class)) {
      return null;
    }
    try {
      Field factoriesField = Gson.class.getDeclaredField("factories");
      factoriesField.setAccessible(true);
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      List<TypeAdapterFactory> factories = (List<TypeAdapterFactory>) factoriesField.get(gson);
      TypeAdapterFactory typeAdapterFactory = factories.stream().filter(f -> f instanceof ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory).findAny().get();
      return typeAdapterFactory.create(gson, type);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException exception) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

This can be registered with

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new CollectionImplementationTypeAdapterFactory());
```

Does someone know a solution without Reflection?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-serialization-part-1) you can use a JsonSerializer.

Note: in the example below I've renamed your class CollectionImpl.

```
public class CollectionImpl implements Collection<String> {

    private final List<String> _wrappedList = new LinkedList<>();
    private String _otherField = "asdf";

    // ...

    // Note: I've created the class as subclass of CollectionImpl in order to access the
    // private fields without implementing a getter (as you maybe want to keep 
    // your fields completely private)
    public static class CollectionImplJsonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<CollectionImpl> {
        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(CollectionImpl src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
            JsonObject jsonColl = new JsonObject();
            JsonArray array = new JsonArray();

            for (String s: src._wrappedList) {
                array.add(s);
            }

            jsonColl.add("_wrappedList", array);
            jsonColl.addProperty("_otherField", src._otherField);


            return jsonColl;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
CollectionImpl ci = new CollectionImpl();

GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
CollectionImpl.CollectionImplJsonSerializer serializer = new CollectionImpl.CollectionImplJsonSerializer();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(CollectionImpl.class, serializer);
Gson gson = builder.create();

String json = gson.toJson(ci);
```

Comment: As already written in my question I'm looking for a solution without manually adding all fields/properties.

Comment: Sorry I missed this line. Don't think you can without implementing a Serializer/Deserializer. Idk what you try to achieve but another option could be for your class to not implement `Collection<>`